# How to get a Checkbox Value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to get a list of the checkbox values when checked and passed them to an input. However, my value is duplicated when I click checkall first. Please help me. Thanks.

My Code

```
<input id="listvalue" name="selectedCB">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" name="checkedAll" id="checkedAll" />
<div class="tycheck">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="2" class="checkSingle" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="1" class="checkSingle" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="3" class="checkSingle" />
</div>

$(document).ready(displayCheckbox);
    var idsArr = [];
    var displayField = $('input[name=selectedCB]');
    function toggle(source) {                    
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.tycheck input[type="checkbox"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i] != source)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            idsArr = [];
            $('#checkall').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                idsArr.push(this.value);
            });
            displayField.val(idsArr);                
        }
    }
    function displayCheckbox() {
        var checkboxes = $(".tycheck input[type=checkbox]");
        function printChecked() {
            var checkedIds = [];
            idsArr = [];
            // for each checked checkbox, add it's id to the array of checked ids
            checkboxes.each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    idsArr.push($(this).attr('value'));
                    console.log(idsArr);
                }
                else {
                    var checkboxesallcheck = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkedAll"]');
                    for (var j = 0; j < checkboxesallcheck.length; j++) {
                        checkboxesallcheck[j].checked = false;

                    }
                }
                displayField.val(idsArr);
            });

        }
        $.each(checkboxes, function () {
            $(this).change(printChecked);
        })
    }
```

How to get a list of the checkbox values when checked and passed them to an input. :(

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for taking the time to help. However, I still don't understand what you mean, you can say it more clearly. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var idsArr = [];
var displayField = $('input[name=selectedCB]');
var checkboxes = Array.from($(".tycheck input[type=checkbox]"));

function toggle(source) {
    var values = checkboxes.map(x => {
      x.checked = source.checked;

      return source.checked ? x.value : '';
    }).join(source.checked ? ',' : '');
      
    displayField.val(values);
}

function printChecked() {
    var values = checkboxes.filter(x => x.checked).map(x => x.value);

    displayField.val(values);
}

$.each(checkboxes, function () {
    $(this).change(printChecked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="listvalue" name="selectedCB">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" name="checkedAll" id="checkedAll" />
<div class="tycheck">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="2" class="checkSingle" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="1" class="checkSingle" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="3" class="checkSingle" />
</div>
```

Comment: For my suggestion don't over use loops for same arr. `filter().map()` for small case is good.For big array its run all the arguments  2 times.for this case jquery default   have [`elem.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) concept  .Use such a map avoid unnecessary array conversion

Comment: Tks guys, happy

Comment: Hi, @Tân Thank you for the help, but it didn't work when activating buttons: ['colvis'] in DataTable, I searched for solutions on the Internet, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @ChimDiTru So, how does it relate to your question above?

Comment: I'm sorry, I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657456/checkbox-click-event-not-working-in-datatable-row-when-buttons-colvis-act. Look forward to your help. Tks

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

1. Use any one of the type `javascript selector or JQuery selector`
2. Not necessary to use `Array` or `forloops` .All function already there in jquery concept .For that we used [`Jquery.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)
3. For below i have simply create one change function call.`checker`
4. Then call that function on checkbox change event in both checkall and normal check event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const elem = $('.tycheck input[type=checkbox]'); //select the checkbox elem
  elem.on('change', function() {
    checker(elem) //get the checked value list
  })
  $('#checkedAll').on('change', function() {
    elem.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked')) //for select all simply compare with checkall button
    checker(elem)
  })
})


function checker(elem) {
  let res = elem.map((i, item) => {
    if ($(item).is(':checked')) {
      return $(item).val()
    }
  }).get()
  $('#listvalue').val(res.toString())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="listvalue" name="selectedCB">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkedAll" id="checkedAll" />
<div class="tycheck">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="2" class="checkSingle" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="1" class="checkSingle" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="3" class="checkSingle" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, @prasanth Thank you for the help, but it didn't work when activating buttons: ['colvis'] in DataTable, I searched for solutions on the Internet, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @ChimDiTru for in you question there is no data tables are present