# Checkbox click event not working in datatable row when buttons: [ 'colvis' ] activeted

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have 1 question here: [How to get a Checkbox Value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59643972/how-to-get-a-checkbox-value-in-javascript/59644269).

- With the help it worked very well. However, when I added buttons: ['colvis'] to DataTable, the click checkbox events did not seem to work correctly. I have looked for help on the DataTable forum, but to no avail.

Code:

```
<input id="listvalue" name="selectedCB">
<table id="datatest" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="no-sort checkboxor">
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" name="checkedAll" id="checkedAll" /> #
        </th>
        <th class="no-sort">IDtest</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="tycheck">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="2" class="checkSingle" />
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tycheck">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="1" class="checkSingle" />
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datatest').DataTable({
            buttons: [
               'colvis'
            ]

        });
});

var idsArr = [];
var displayField = $('input[name=selectedCB]');
var checkboxes = Array.from($(".tycheck input[type=checkbox]"));
function toggle(source) {
var values = checkboxes.map(x => {
  x.checked = source.checked;

  return source.checked ? x.value : '';
}).join(source.checked ? ',' : '');

displayField.val(values);
}
function printChecked() {
var values = checkboxes.filter(x => x.checked).map(x => x.value);

displayField.val(values);
}
$.each(checkboxes, function () {
$(this).change(printChecked);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you may need to update the event `onchange` for the checkbox `#checkedAll`.

Since you want to use it with jquery, you can remove the attribute `onclick="toggle(this)"` from

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" name="checkedAll" id="checkedAll" />
```

Then, in your js file, you can write the event like this

```
$('#checkedAll').on('change', toggle);
```

Then, because we use `toggle` function as the event for this checkbox, we don't need `source` parameter anymore, just replace it with `this`:

```
function toggle() {
  var values = checkboxes.map(x => {
    x.checked = this.checked;

    return this.checked ? x.value : '';
  }).join(this.checked ? ',' : '');

  displayField.val(values);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datatest').DataTable({
        buttons: [
           'colvis'
        ]

    });
});

var idsArr = [];
var displayField = $('input[name=selectedCB]');
var checkboxes = Array.from($(".tycheck input[type=checkbox]"));

function toggle() {
  var values = checkboxes.map(x => {
    x.checked = this.checked;

    return this.checked ? x.value : '';
  }).join(this.checked ? ',' : '');

  displayField.val(values);
}

function printChecked() {
  var values = checkboxes.filter(x => x.checked).map(x => x.value);

  displayField.val(values);
}

$.each(checkboxes, function () {
  $(this).on('change', printChecked);
});

$('#checkedAll').on('change', toggle);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<input id="listvalue" name="selectedCB">
<table id="datatest" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="no-sort checkboxor">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedAll" id="checkedAll" /> #
        </th>
        <th class="no-sort">IDtest</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="tycheck">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="2" class="checkSingle" />
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tycheck">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="1" class="checkSingle" />
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```